# Save screen capture in a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my webpage I have a table like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQGTG.png) and clicking the button you see below I want to take a screen of that table. That table is not a picture, I did it with HTML and CSS code.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$('savetab').click(function() {
var testdiv = document.getElementById("testdiv");
    html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            var a= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            window.open(a);
        },       
    });
});
</script>
```

This code takes the screenshot of `testdiv`, which is a div that contains that table. Here you can see the code of the 'Save table' button:

```
<p align="center"><input type="button" value="Save table" id="savetab1" /></p>
```

I have two questions:

1. According with the code above, when I click `savetab` the script must open the screenshot but it doesn't. I don't have any error in the console and I don't see anything.
2. I'd like to save that picture in my server. I have prepared a php file with some code that saves a picture on the server, I only have to pass that pic. I have read a lot of stuff on google and I have found that I can do it with **ajax**. Do you have any good examples?

Comment: R u wrap the code inside the $(function(){})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `$('savetab')` must be `$('#savetab1')`

change your script like this

```
 <script language="javascript">
    $(function(){
     $('#savetab1').on('click',function() {
     var testdiv = document.getElementById("testdiv");
        html2canvas($("#testdiv"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
                var a= canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                window.open(a);
            }       
        });
     });
   });
    </script>
```